# Data source for average effective personal income tax rate?

Tags: data-request, taxation

Anyone know a source for the average effective personal income tax rate for the US. By state also would be great.

Definition: average effective income tax rate = (Total income tax collected)/(Total income earned)

Possibly a source for the data to do the calculation.

Comment: What you defined (total income tax collected/total income) is the average effective tax rate, not the marginal rate.

Comment: @dismalscience, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a lot of things, including [average effective (Federal) tax rates](http://www.taxpolicycenter.org/taxfacts/displayafact.cfm?Docid=456), the Urban Institute/Brookings Institution Tax Policy Center is a great place to start. Look at the table that reads "Average Individual Income Tax Rate," as the first one also includes payroll, excise, and corporate taxes.

Comment: This table almost has it, to bad they did not include to total effective.
http://www.taxpolicycenter.org/taxfacts/displayafact.cfm?Docid=366
I am really only looking for an estimate, looks like it might be about 5-6%

Comment: Check the "all quintiles" column of the table in the link I provided if you want the average of effective rates across everyone in the US.

Comment: ok so about 8.4 for 2011. Thanks a bunch!